# how to put 2 different Fragments in a BottomNavigationView?

Tags: android, kotlin, bottomnavigationview

I try to put a BottomNavigationView like this in my main Activity, and I have a recycler view too :

```
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        loadFragment(HomeFragment(this))

        //import the bottomNavigationView
        val navigationView = findViewById<BottomNavigationView>(R.id.barre_nav)
        navigationView.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener {
            when(it.itemId) {
                R.id.nav_home -> {
                    loadFragment(HomeFragment(this))
                    return@setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener true
                }
                R.id.nav_choose -> {
                    loadFragment(ChooserFragment(ChooserActivity()))
                    return@setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener true
                }
                else -> false
            }
        }
    }

    private fun loadFragment(fragment: Fragment) {
        val transactionMuscle = supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction()
        transactionMuscle.replace(R.id.fragment_container, fragment)
        transactionMuscle.addToBackStack(null)
        transactionMuscle.commit()
    }
```

But my problem with this code which is fine if I would to put the two view in the same container, but I wouldn't, is : I have a ChooserActivity and I would the second part of my bottomNavigationView to redirect to this page, and not the MainActivity Fragment with the Chooser composant. I would do the same as it do for the main Activity but with the ChooserActivity.
I doesn't know if I am clear, but I Thank you in advance.

EDIT to clarify :
My aim is to with mybottomNavigationView, when we click on the first button, it redirect to the MainActivity, and when we click on the second button, it redirect to the ChooserActivity. Th two must have there own containers. Hopefully it is better...

Comment: please elaborate your problem, or clarify it in better way ..
edit your question, define your problem in steps so may it will be unambiguous or understandable.

Comment: it is done, hopefully it will help you to resolve it... @ahmednawazCS

Answer (score 0):

**Solution**
try this code:

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        val bottomNavigation: BottomNavigationView = findViewById(R.id.barre_nav)
        bottomNavigation.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(mOnNavigationItemSelectedListener)
    } //onCreate() end here

    private val mOnNavigationItemSelectedListener = BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener { item ->
        when (item.itemId) {
            R.id.nav_home -> {

                val homeFragment = HomeFragment.newInstance()
                loadFragment(homeFragment)
                return@OnNavigationItemSelectedListener true
            }
            R.id.nav_choose -> {

                val chooserFragment = ChooserFragment.newInstance()
                loadFragment(chooserFragment)
                return@OnNavigationItemSelectedListener true
            }
        }
        false
    }

    private fun loadFragment(fragment: Fragment) {
        val transactionMuscle = supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction()
        transactionMuscle.replace(R.id.fragment_container, fragment)
        transactionMuscle.addToBackStack(null)
        transactionMuscle.commit()
    }
```

**In You Fragments OnCreateView() Method** add these lines too :

1.HomeFragment

```
companion object {
        fun newInstance(): HomeFragment = HomeFragment()
    }
```

2.ChooserFragment

```
companion object {
        fun newInstance(): ChooserFragment= ChooserFragment()
    }
```

Hope so it works :)

If you still face any issue , please add it into comments

Comment: I have tried and it changes nothing.  Maybe because I can't add companion objects to the OnCreateView method, but in the class directly. If I add it in the OnCreateView, it says me that I should create a Companion method. Thank you for your help ! @ahmednawazCS